# Accessing vuex store state array details in another Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a marketplace and I store chosen products from localstorage in `cart` in `Vuex Store` as a `JSON` to share them with other components. Now when client buys products I want to access `cart` details and store it in the DB with their name and other info, but I cannot access `JSON` details I want from `Vuex Store`.

Vuex:

```
let cart = window.localStorage.getItem('cart')

const store = createStore({
    state: {
        cart: cart ? JSON.parse(cart) : [],
    },
})
```

checkout Vue component:
With `.map()` I get another array and I want to get a single value. I have also tried `.forEach()` but I get the value of undefined.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
  
      customers: {
        name:'',
        adress:'',
        town:'',
        email:'',
        phone:'',
        title : this.$store.state.cart.map(function (detail){
          return detail.ropeTitle
        }),
        diameter: this.$store.state.cart.map(function (detail) {
          return detail.ropeDiameter
        }),
        price: this.$store.state.cart.map(function (detail) {
          return detail.ropePrice
        }),
        cartQuantity: this.$store.state.cart.map(function (detail) {
          return detail.ropeQuantity
        })

      },
     
    }
     
  },
    methods: {
    async handleSubmitForm() {
      try {
        await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/orders/customers', this.customers)
            .then(() => {
              this.$router.push('/customers')
              this.customers = {
                name:'',
                adress:'',
                town:'',
                email:'',
                phone:'',
                title : '',
                diameter: '',
                price: '',
                cartQuantity: '',



              }
              router.go(-1)
            })
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        console.log(this.customers)

      }
    }
  }

}
```

Can you please help?

Comment: "... store them in the DB, but i cannot access details i want from Vuex store" What does that even mean? Can you please try to specify what the problem is? Then I will try to help you.

Comment: i am sorry... to simplify i want to access ropeTitle, ropeName, diameter, price, from my Vuex JSON parsed cart array, as you can see in my vue component. I have tried with .map() but i get just another array.

Comment: You should either get the state as a whole object or split the object in your store and serve the details as seperate states. For example `ropePrice` as a seperate state and `this.$store.state.ropePrice` to call it. And according to that you should use `getters` to better coordination of your data handling.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that... i have updated my code... you can check vuex code... cart data is coming from local storage....

Answer (score 0):

so I made details as separate states in getters like this:

```
 setTitle: state =>{
           let oneItem=''
            state.cart.forEach((item)=>{
                oneItem=item.ropeTitle
            })

            return oneItem
        },
```

and then I used it in a component like this:

```
title : this.$store.getters.setTitle,
```